# C++ lambda two copy constructor calls

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, lambda, copy-constructor

I have the following code snippet.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    A() { cout << "A "; data = 1; }
    A(const A& a) { cout << "cA "; data = a.data; }
    ~A() { cout << " dA"; }
    int data;
};

void f(A& a, function<void(A)> f)
{
    cout << "(";
    f(a);
    cout << ")";
}

int main()
{
    A temp;
    auto fun = [](A a) {cout << a.data;};
    f(temp, fun);
}
```

The output is:

> A (cA cA 1 dA dA) dA

Why is `temp` copied twice?

I am using Visual C++ (vc140).

Comment: You're missing the declaration of `function<>`, but I'd guess it's happening in there.

Comment: @PaulEvans How is it missing? `#include <functional>` is there, `using namespace std;` (while poor practice) is there.

Comment: @Angew Sorry - my bad.  Building in the wrong directory :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`function<void(A)>` has a function-call operator with this signature: `operator()(A)` i.e. it takes its argument by value, so calling `f(a)` makes a copy.

The lambda also takes its argument by value, so when that is called inside the `function<void(A)>` call operator another copy gets made.

If you define a move constructor for `A` you should see that initializing the lambda argument (from the first copy made by the `function`) can be a move instead of a copy, but only if the type has a move constructor. Otherwise it has to be copied.

Alternatively, if you use `std::function<void(const A&)>` then the call operator will take its argument by reference not by value, so there is only one copy made, to initialize the argument of the lambda.